# Right django decorator

Tags: django

I have copied code of django decorator, and changed it for my purposes

```
def valid_token_required(function=None):

    def _dec(view_func):
        def _view(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if 'token' in request.session:
                try:
                    conn = server.GetTokenCon(request.session['token'])
                    if conn.get_api_status().status == 'good':
                        kwargs['Connection'] = conn
                        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
                except RateLimitExceededException as e:
                    return HttpResponseForbidden('token_limit')
                except BadCredentialsException as e:
                    return HttpResponseForbidden('badkey')
            return HttpResponseForbidden('require_token')

        _view.__name__ = view_func.__name__
        _view.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
        _view.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__

        return _view

    if function is None:
        return _dec
    else:
        return _dec(function)
```

All is OK, but I can't understand the sense of this lines, I have tried to delete them and code continue work. Can somebody explain the meaning of this lines?

```
_view.__name__ = view_func.__name__
_view.__dict__ = view_func.__dict__
_view.__doc__ = view_func.__doc__
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changes the innermost function (`_view`) so it appears to have the same name, attributes, and documentation as the function it wraps. This aids when using `help()` in the Python interpreter, and makes stack traces more clear.

(Note: The same thing is basically done by the `functools.wraps` decorator included in the stdlib.)